# why my merge sort code is giving an index error

Tags: python

I have written a code for merge sort following the pseudocode given in "introduction to algorithms" by Cormen, but as I run my code I'm getting a long traceback error followed by an index error of list assignment index out of range.
the code is as follows:

```
def merge(a, p, q, r):
    n = q-p+1
    m = r-q
    b = [0]*(n)
    c = [0]*(m)
    for i in range(0, n):
        b[i] = a[p+i]
    for j in range(0, m):
        c[i] = a[q+1+j]
    b[n+1] = math.inf
    c[m+1] = math.inf
    i = 0
    j = 0

    for k in range(p, r+1):
        if b[i] < c[j]:
            a[k] = b[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            a[k] = c[j]
            j += 1


def mergesort(a, p, r):
    if p < r:
        q = (p+r)//2
        mergesort(a, p, q)
        mergesort(a, q+1, r)
        merge(a, p, q, r)


a = [4, 0, 6, 1, 5, 2, 3]
n = len(a)
print(*a, sep=" ")
mergesort(a, 0, n-1)
for i in range(0, n):
    print("the  sorted array is", a[i])
```

the code is giving the following traceback error:

```
  File "m.py", line 38, in <module>
    mergesort(a, 0, n-1)
  File "m.py", line 30, in mergesort
    mergesort(a, p, q)
  File "m.py", line 30, in mergesort
    mergesort(a, p, q)
  File "m.py", line 32, in mergesort
    merge(a, p, q, r)
  File "m.py", line 13, in merge
    b[n+1] = math.inf
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: You make `b` `n` elements long and then try to access `n+1`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
    b[n+1] = math.inf
    c[m+1] = math.inf
```

use

```
    b.append(math.inf)
    c.append(math.inf)
```

Comment: I'm still getting the traceback followed by the index error; list  assignment index out of range except that  line 13 has been removed  from the traceback

Comment: I would suggest that instead of manually specifying what position in the list to place an item (list[index] = value), since all you are doing is adding things to the end of the list, consider using the append method. That is replace b[i] = a[p+i] with b.append(a[p+i]) and c[i] = a[q+1+j] with c.append( a[q+1+j])